# Find and replace multiple character in a string VBA

Tags: vba, excel, replace, excel-2010

I have a large amount of data which i want to replace with the help of macro. I am using code below right now but problem is that it will only replace one value which is D in below code.

```
Sub Replace()

what = "D"
replc = ""

Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Cells.replace What:=word, Replacement:=replc, LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

My sample data is below. As you can see that some value have alphabetical characters, symbol or combination of character at the end or as a cell value, which i want to replace or remove and also some value will be replaced with other values. I create macro with all possibilities to find the required value and replace it.

**0065D**   2089    2797    3270    3315
**0066D**   2095    2799    3300    3334
**0067D**   2105    2802    **3582aX**  **a**
2089    –   2812    3307    3383
2095    2111    **1164D**   3315    3385
2105    2112    **1165D**   3334    3400
2110    2114    2841    **3336F**   3507
**0771N**   2121    2881    3365    **3515N**
**0908P**   2130    2883    **3372X**   3548
**0913P**   2131    2913    3373    3559
2111    2143    2915    3373    3574

You also notice that there are some lower case characters as well. Right now i was trying to use **IF** condition with **Find** but could not succeed. I am making above macro with every possible condition to replace and run it from another macro which is something like below algo.

```
IF  find "D"  Then

Run macro "Replace"

Elseif  find "X"

Run macro "Replace"

Elseif  find "F"

Run macro "Replace"

and so on....
```

but if the macro didn't find required character in the sheet then it skips to next step and so on. I want this so bad. I have to perform this replace routine on number of times.

So any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So for say `D`, you want to replace the cell contents with what? For example old value is `0065D`. What would be the new value?

Comment: or do you want to remove all the alphabets from numbers?

Comment: If the value occur like `6500D`, I have to remove D or replace it with empty space. But when value is only `a` then I have to replace it with 0. For other values scenario will be changed.

Answer (score 3):

You can add/remove necessary characters from the `toRemove()` array.

```
Sub replaceChars()
Dim toRemove()

toRemove() = Array("D", "X", "F")

For Each itm In toRemove()
    For Each iCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        iCell.Replace What:=itm, Replacement:="", MatchCase:=True
    Next iCell
Next itm

End Sub
```